# gpg key for ubuntu trusty-security. (Deprecation of apt-key)

Tags: apt, updates, keyrings

I need your help with apt-key deprecation issue.

I am aware that this topic has been discussed countless times however my query is related to finding the correct gpg-key.

Since I upgraded my Ubuntu from 20.04 LTS to 22.04 LTS, I am getting the following warning.

```
All packages are up to date.
W: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
```

I know the problem lies with the misplaced gpg key, so I tried to follow https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2022/06/fix-apt-key-deprecation-error-on-ubuntu to fix the issue.
However, I could not find the key for trusty-security in the apt-key list.

Could anyone help me identify the correct key for trusty-security?

The key list is as follows.

```
sudo apt-key list
Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).
/etc/apt/trusted.gpg
--------------------
pub   rsa1024 2016-04-26 [SCEA]
      61AC 9078 FAA4 CB93 FC9E  8962 E17B FDD4 3DF7 1FB4
uid           [ unknown] live-build local packages key <live-build-local-key@invalid>
sub   elg1024 2016-04-26 [E]

pub   dsa1024 2005-05-24 [SC]
      3B59 3C7B E6DB 6A89 FB7C  BFFD 058A 05E9 0C4E CFEC
uid           [ unknown] Ubuntu-ja Archive Automatic Signing Key <archive@ubuntulinux.jp>
sub   elg2048 2005-05-24 [E]

pub   rsa1024 2009-04-05 [SC]
      5967 6CBC F5DF D8C1 CEFE  375B 68B5 F60D CDC1 D865
uid           [ unknown] Launchpad PPA for Ubuntu Japanese Team

pub   rsa4096 2016-04-12 [SC]
      EB4C 1BFD 4F04 2F6D DDCC  EC91 7721 F63B D38B 4796
uid           [ unknown] Google Inc. (Linux Packages Signing Authority) <linux-packages-keymaster@google.com>
sub   rsa4096 2021-10-26 [S] [expires: 2024-10-25]

pub   rsa2048 2010-10-19 [SCA] [expires: 2027-09-30]
      E298 A3A8 25C0 D65D FD57  CBB6 5171 6619 E084 DAB9
uid           [ unknown] Michael Rutter <marutter@gmail.com>
sub   rsa2048 2010-10-19 [E] [expires: 2027-09-30]

pub   rsa1024 2016-11-19 [C]
      CF80 5866 AEBD 8266 5423  554F 4359 ED62 E084 DAB9
uid           [ unknown] Totally Legit Signing Key <mallory@example.org>

pub   rsa2048 2017-06-23 [SC] [expires: 2023-04-29]
      D6BC 2435 65B2 087B C3F8  97C9 277A 7293 F59E 4889
uid           [ unknown] MiKTeX Packager <packager@miktex.org>
sub   rsa2048 2017-06-23 [E] [expires: 2023-04-29]

pub   dsa1024 2004-09-12 [SC]
      6302 39CC 130E 1A7F D81A  27B1 4097 6EAF 437D 05B5
uid           [ unknown] Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>
sub   elg2048 2004-09-12 [E]

pub   rsa4096 2012-05-11 [SC]
      790B C727 7767 219C 42C8  6F93 3B4F E6AC C0B2 1F32
uid           [ unknown] Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key (2012) <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/apandada1_ubuntu_brightness-controller.gpg
-----------------------------------------------------------------
pub   rsa1024 2013-03-25 [SC]
      95AC DEBD 8BFF 99AB E0F2  6A49 A507 B2BB A780 3E3B
uid           [ unknown] Launchpad PPA for Archisman Panigrahi

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/beineri_ubuntu_opt-qt-5_11_1-xenial.gpg
--------------------------------------------------------------
pub   rsa1024 2012-11-17 [SC]
      C65D 5178 4EDC 19A8 71DB  DBB7 10C5 6D0D E997 7759
uid           [ unknown] Launchpad PPA for Stephan Binner

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/c2d4u_team-ubuntu-c2d4u4_0_.gpg
------------------------------------------------------
pub   rsa4096 2020-04-13 [SC]
      6E12 762B 8106 3D17 BDDD  3142 F142 A4D9 9F16 EB04
uid           [ unknown] Launchpad PPA for cran2deb4ubuntu Build Team

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/c2d4u_team_ubuntu_c2d4u4_0_.gpg
------------------------------------------------------
pub   rsa4096 2020-04-13 [SC]
      6E12 762B 8106 3D17 BDDD  3142 F142 A4D9 9F16 EB04
uid           [ unknown] Launchpad PPA for cran2deb4ubuntu Build Team

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/gnome3-team_ubuntu_gnome3.gpg
----------------------------------------------------
pub   rsa1024 2010-12-15 [SC]
      9D54 2E3D 52C8 01D9 F8E3  1682 F177 3AF1 3B15 10FD
uid           [ unknown] Launchpad PPA for GNOME3 Team

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/gnome3-team_ubuntu_gnome3-staging.gpg
------------------------------------------------------------
pub   rsa1024 2010-12-15 [SC]
      9D54 2E3D 52C8 01D9 F8E3  1682 F177 3AF1 3B15 10FD
uid           [ unknown] Launchpad PPA for GNOME3 Team

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/google-chrome.gpg
----------------------------------------
pub   rsa4096 2016-04-12 [SC]
      EB4C 1BFD 4F04 2F6D DDCC  EC91 7721 F63B D38B 4796
uid           [ unknown] Google Inc. (Linux Packages Signing Authority) <linux-packages-keymaster@google.com>
sub   rsa4096 2021-10-26 [S] [expires: 2024-10-25]

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/libreoffice-ubuntu-ppa.gpg
-------------------------------------------------
pub   rsa1024 2010-12-29 [SC]
      36E8 1C92 67FD 1383 FCC4  4909 83FB A175 1378 B444
uid           [ unknown] Launchpad PPA for LibreOffice Packaging

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/libreoffice_ubuntu_ppa.gpg
-------------------------------------------------
pub   rsa1024 2010-12-29 [SC]
      36E8 1C92 67FD 1383 FCC4  4909 83FB A175 1378 B444
uid           [ unknown] Launchpad PPA for LibreOffice Packaging

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/lyx-devel-ubuntu-release.gpg
---------------------------------------------------
pub   rsa1024 2012-02-19 [SC]
      EDE9 A110 9EB3 355B 5911  59DC A648 33C9 F821 4ACD
uid           [ unknown] Launchpad PPA for LyX Team

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/lyx-devel_ubuntu_release.gpg
---------------------------------------------------
pub   rsa1024 2012-02-19 [SC]
      EDE9 A110 9EB3 355B 5911  59DC A648 33C9 F821 4ACD
uid           [ unknown] Launchpad PPA for LyX Team

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/michael-gruz_ubuntu_canon.gpg
----------------------------------------------------
pub   rsa1024 2009-10-18 [SC]
      84E5 50CD 36EC 3543 0A66  AC5A 0339 6E1C 3F7B 4A1D
uid           [ unknown] Launchpad Misakovi

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/microsoft-edge-beta.gpg
----------------------------------------------
pub   rsa4096 2016-04-12 [SC]
      EB4C 1BFD 4F04 2F6D DDCC  EC91 7721 F63B D38B 4796
uid           [ unknown] Google Inc. (Linux Packages Signing Authority) <linux-packages-keymaster@google.com>
sub   rsa4096 2021-10-26 [S] [expires: 2024-10-25]

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/microsoft.gpg
------------------------------------
pub   rsa2048 2015-10-28 [SC]
      BC52 8686 B50D 79E3 39D3  721C EB3E 94AD BE12 29CF
uid           [ unknown] Microsoft (Release signing) <gpgsecurity@microsoft.com>

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/mozillateam-ubuntu-ppa.gpg
-------------------------------------------------
pub   rsa1024 2009-01-18 [SC]
      0AB2 1567 9C57 1D1C 8325  275B 9BDB 3D89 CE49 EC21
uid           [ unknown] Launchpad PPA for Mozilla Team

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/mozillateam_ubuntu_ppa.gpg
-------------------------------------------------
pub   rsa1024 2009-01-18 [SC]
      0AB2 1567 9C57 1D1C 8325  275B 9BDB 3D89 CE49 EC21
uid           [ unknown] Launchpad PPA for Mozilla Team

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/qgis-archive.gpg
---------------------------------------
pub   rsa4096 2020-08-08 [SCEA] [expired: 2021-08-08]
      3987 7635 093F 2656 0197  11FA F7E0 6F06 199E F2F2
uid           [ expired] QGIS Archive Automatic Signing Key (2020) <qgis-developer@lists.osgeo.org>

pub   rsa4096 2021-08-09 [SCEA] [expired: 2022-08-09]
      2445 D6B2 54DA C452 A498  989E 46B5 721D BBD2 996A
uid           [ expired] QGIS Archive Automatic Signing Key (2021) <qgis-developer@lists.osgeo.org>

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/remmina-ppa-team-ubuntu-remmina-next-daily.gpg
---------------------------------------------------------------------
pub   rsa4096 2014-11-20 [SC]
      04E3 8CE1 34B2 39B9 F38F  82EE 8A99 3C25 21C5 F0BA
uid           [ unknown] Launchpad PPA for Remmina PPA Team

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/remmina-ppa-team_ubuntu_remmina-next.gpg
---------------------------------------------------------------
pub   rsa4096 2014-11-20 [SC]
      04E3 8CE1 34B2 39B9 F38F  82EE 8A99 3C25 21C5 F0BA
uid           [ unknown] Launchpad PPA for Remmina PPA Team

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/shemgp_ubuntu_gnome-40.gpg
-------------------------------------------------
pub   rsa1024 2009-01-22 [SC]
      63E7 F399 F8A4 7651 4BA0  6E1D 5A12 0BFC E2F0 28D4
uid           [ unknown] Launchpad PPA for shemgp

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/thierry-f_ubuntu_fork-michael-gruz.gpg
-------------------------------------------------------------
pub   rsa4096 2018-07-24 [SC]
      E85C CE01 4112 1326 59E6  F35D 3BA6 E6CC E411 CFCF
uid           [ unknown] Launchpad PPA for Thierry HUCHARD

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ubuntugis-ubuntu-ppa.gpg
-----------------------------------------------
pub   rsa1024 2009-05-10 [SC]
      6B82 7C12 C2D4 25E2 27ED  CA75 089E BE08 314D F160
uid           [ unknown] Launchpad ubuntugis-stable

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ubuntugis_ubuntu_ppa.gpg
-----------------------------------------------
pub   rsa1024 2009-05-10 [SC]
      6B82 7C12 C2D4 25E2 27ED  CA75 089E BE08 314D F160
uid           [ unknown] Launchpad ubuntugis-stable

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ubuntugis_ubuntu_ubuntugis-unstable.gpg
--------------------------------------------------------------
pub   rsa1024 2009-05-10 [SC]
      6B82 7C12 C2D4 25E2 27ED  CA75 089E BE08 314D F160
uid           [ unknown] Launchpad ubuntugis-stable

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ubuntu-keyring-2012-cdimage.gpg
------------------------------------------------------
pub   rsa4096 2012-05-11 [SC]
      8439 38DF 228D 22F7 B374  2BC0 D94A A3F0 EFE2 1092
uid           [ unknown] Ubuntu CD Image Automatic Signing Key (2012) <cdimage@ubuntu.com>

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ubuntu-keyring-2018-archive.gpg
------------------------------------------------------
pub   rsa4096 2018-09-17 [SC]
      F6EC B376 2474 EDA9 D21B  7022 8719 20D1 991B C93C
uid           [ unknown] Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key (2018) <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ubuntu-mozilla-daily-ubuntu-ppa.gpg
----------------------------------------------------------
pub   rsa1024 2009-02-05 [SC]
      B345 05EA 326F EAEA 07E3  618D EF41 86FE 2475 10BE
uid           [ unknown] Launchpad PPA for Ubuntu Mozilla Daily Build Team

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ubuntu-mozilla-daily_ubuntu_ppa.gpg
----------------------------------------------------------
pub   rsa1024 2009-02-05 [SC]
      B345 05EA 326F EAEA 07E3  618D EF41 86FE 2475 10BE
uid           [ unknown] Launchpad PPA for Ubuntu Mozilla Daily Build Team
```

Comment: Why would you want it?  *trusty* refers to the 2014-April (14.04) release which reached EOSS or *end of standard support* in April 2019, thus why would it have anything useful/safe for a modern Ubuntu system?   It should be removed !

Comment: Sorry, but I am not sure about its functionality. Every time I upgraded to the newer version, Ubuntu kept it as it was in the older version (including the repository). Also, in the repository list, it is labeled as "Important Security Updates," so I thought it would be necessary. If it's okay to remove it, I will do so.

Comment: When you *release-upgraded* it would have been disabled, starting with when upgrading from 14.04 to 16.04 (ie. *a "#" added to the start of the line so it was ignored*), so someone with `sudo` rights would have had to re-enable it (*removed the "#" at the start of the line*), or IF this is a desktop system re-enabled it via GUI tool after each *release-upgrade*.  *trusty* was 14.04; *xenial* was 16.04, *bionic* was 18.04, *focal* was 20.04 & *jammy* is 22.04.  The default is to disable (ie. *comment out*) as it's not removed on upgrade.

Comment: I understand. In that case, I will remove it from the system. Thank you for helping me.